# Could not load id_rsa as a RSA1 public key

Tags: ssh

I'm using cygwin on Windows 7 64 bit and I'm trying to `ssh -vvv localhost`

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/habdulmalak/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

The public key was generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and the public key was added to the authorized_keys file.

Any clue?

Comment: What does the beginning of `/home/habdulmalak/.ssh/id_rsa` look like?

Comment: Is this the path to the RSA Public Key  .. /home/habdulmalak/.ssh/id_rsa ??

Comment: this is the path of the id_rsa C:\cygwin\home\myusername\.ssh

Comment: the question here is why it needs an rsa1 public key? i need to use RSA

Comment: This question is off-topic here. There is a very similar question on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), where it is on-topic: [What's this SSH error about “incorrect RSA1 identifier” and “unspecified GSS failure”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57637/whats-this-ssh-error-about-incorrect-rsa1-identifier-and-unspecified-gss-fai)

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. The messages about RSA1 are expected: SSH looks if you have a key for the SSH v1 protocol, and you don't (you have a key for the SSH v2 protocl), which is fine because SSH v1 has been obsolete for years. If you can't log in, it's for some other reason. It's quite likely that the permissions on the `authorized_keys` file or the containing directory are wrong: read http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info and check the server logs.

Answer (score 29):

Shortly speaking, it doesn't indicate an error. It's normal.

You can reference my answer here:
[Trying to use RSA Keys to SSH into EC2, Getting: Incorrect RSA1 identifier... permission denied (public key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449626/trying-to-use-rsa-keys-to-ssh-into-ec2-getting-incorrect-rsa1-identifier-pe/15563793#15563793)

Answer (score 5):

As stated in comments, this error is OK.

Did you check /etc/hosts.deny? My guess is you have an `sshd: x.x.x.x` entry in there

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realized the reason why I was getting the same error was because sshd was not running on the VM server I was trying to connect to :) Running it fixed the prob for me.