# ssh: Connection closed by IP, after SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to ssh into my own laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) from another linux machine. I get the error "Connection closed by `IP`" where `IP` is the IP address of my laptop. Here is the verbose output (`$HOME` is the home directory):

```
$ ssh kaiyu@LAPTOP_IP -p 24 -vvv
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data $HOME/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to LAPTOP_IP [LAPTOP_IP] port 24.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [LAPTOP_IP]:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[LAPTOP_IP]:24" from file "/homes/iws/qaz2wsx3/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by LAPTOP_IP
```

I cannot find online how to resolve this issue. When I try to ssh localhost on my own laptop, I get the exact same debugging output, but the error message is `Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer`.

Even though in the debugging output, there is a line that says `Could not load "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key`, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15563842/2893053), this message is normal.

Here are some additional information about my setup:

**OpenSSH Version**: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8

**sshd_config**:

```
Port 24
AuthenticationMethods publickey
# ListenAddress 192.168.1.1
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
ServerKeyBits 1024
LoginGraceTime 600
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
PermitRootLogin no
IgnoreRhosts yes
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
StrictModes yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd yes
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
RhostsAuthentication no
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

Is there anything wrong with this configuration? Why is that error happening, and why does it happen after `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent`? How to resolve this issue?

Thank you sincerely!

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall the ssh bits by doing

> sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server openssh-client